2019: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
  -- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Quantitative Finance over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  3          9
Users destroyed³                                 18          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                   5          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue           135        475
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue               10         66
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         31        132
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue               38        235
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                56      1,548
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue              104      1,201
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Tag synonyms created                              2          0
Questions reopened                               11          0
Questions protected                               0          6
Questions migrated                               13          0
Questions merged                                  2          0
Questions flagged⁵                                0         98
Questions closed                                338        185
Question flags handled⁵                          58         40
Posts unlocked                                    0          3
Posts undeleted                                   6         46
Posts locked                                      1         17
Posts deleted⁶                                  206      1,430
Posts bumped                                      0        768
Comments undeleted                                7          0
Comments flagged                                  0        385
Comments deleted⁷                                60      1,480
Comment flags handled                            51        334
Answers flagged                                   0        348
Answer flags handled                            322         26
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Quantitative Finance without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).   
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: 2018: a year in moderation...
You can also check out this report on other sites
Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites

Wishing you all a happy new year...
